# OpenSSL custom development

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, ssl, openssl

I am trying to modify OpenSSL code which is available from http://www.openssl.org/source/ as part of my school project. I am very new to C development. I have created a very simple client-server application using SSL. I have compiled and installed OpenSSL library. When I run it, I use libssl-dev package for SSL header files on Ubuntu. Now I was wondering, if I modify OpenSSL code and want to test my application using modified code how can I specify to gcc to use my modified source instead of standard code? Currently I am using following command to compile my code: `gcc filename.c /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a -ldl`

Comment: Recompile & reinstall the libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's assume that your modified library is installed under `/usr/local/ssl`, you can use the following commands to compile your code:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/ssl -o foo.o -c foo.c
gcc -I/usr/include/ssl -o bar.o -c bar.c
```

and the following to link:

```
gcc -o my_prog foo.o bar.o -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto -ldl
```

The -L will make the libraries in that directory take precedence over the ones that are implicitly defined in gcc configs

A basic Makefile could be:

```
CC=gcc
INCLUDE=-I/usr/include/ssl

# other C-preprocessor flags
CPPFLAGS=-DFOO  

# Linker flags

LDFLAGS=

# Libraries
LIBS=-L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto -ldl

# Source files 

SOURCES=foo.c bar.c
OBJS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)

# dummy default target

default: my_prog

# rule to build my_prog:
my_prog: $(OBJS)
       $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

# clean
clean:
     $(RM) my_prog $(OBJS)

# rule to convert .c to .o

%.o: %.c
     $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: That means I need to compile OpenSSL library every time, I modify the code inside it. isn't it?